# Unable to see the dropdown of a inputText box it hid behind the keyboard in react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Tags: react-native, autocomplete

I am using react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view to see the input box above the keyboard. It working fine.

But one of my input boxes has a dropdown. It is hidden behind the keyboard. I have tried setting the margin values. It did not work for me.

Any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

React Native's `EditText` has the`isFocused ()`props that checks to see if it is focused.
You can call a function that raises your list when `EditText` is in focus, and to go down when focus is false.
Use a `Timeout` because otherwise`EditText` will not go at the same time as your list.
Not a good solution I know, but you can also try this with animation to improve it a bit.

Comment: If I click on the input box the focus are working fine. Also the inputbox is shown above the keyboard. But the dropdown only not show above the keyboard it hide behind the keyboard.